# How do I identify the SMD component marked as !3S 4?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, markings

I have a SOT-23 SMD component marked \$\underset{\bullet}{\vert}3\bar{\textrm{S}}\;\bar{4}\$ as shown in the following images

[image: Marking code pic 1]

[image: Marking code pic 2]

I managed to find out that \$\textrm{3S}\$ stands for MMBT5551 NPN transistor. But I couldn't find the meaning of the prefix \$\underset{\bullet}{\vert}\$ and of the \$\bar{4}\$. I appreciate any help you can give me with it.

Comment: BTW, +1 for the excellent markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bars on the top of the S and 4 mean "Non Lead-Free Marking".
Production year is 2005, week 4.

The dot of the \$\underset{\bullet}{\vert}\$ mark is the pin 1 marking (do check the datasheet, it has a pin *numbering* as well).

The combination of \$\underset{\bullet}{\vert}\$ means it was manufactured by a Philippine Subcontractor.

[RoHS- Compliant Product Identification](https://docplayer.net/50474250-Fairchild-semiconductor-s-rohs-compliant-product-identification-february-23-kirk-olund-member-of-q-r-technical-staff.html)

Comment: I knew the bars had to do with RoHS-Compliance (non compiance in this case). That's the way how I found the linked document.